# Front matter defaults for collection's documents in subfolders

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I would like to organize collection's documents in subfolders and assign them different categories through front matter defaults. I have the following structure:

```
_kb
    - category1
        - article1.md
    - category2
        - article2.md
```

In my _config.yml file I have:

```
# Collections
collections:
  kb:
    output: true
    permalink: /kb/:name/

# Defaults
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "_kb/category1/"
      type: "kb"
    values:
      category: "category1"
  -
    scope:
      path: "_kb/category2/"
      type: "kb"
    values:
      category: "category2"
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea how I can assign different categories to documents in different subfolders through front-matter defaults?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are looking for is possible.

Reading the [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/), it should be possible. But I have done some experimentation with Jekyll 2.4 and the "path" appears to be the result of the permalink conversion.

With your example setup I added this as a set of defaults

```
-
  scope:
    path: "kb/article1/"
    type: "kb"
  values:
    category: "category6"
```

The generated file got "category6" assigned to it.

Comment: Hello David, thank you very much! I see what you mean. As for the example, I have several articles in each subfolder. And I guess for me it's easier to specify the category in YAML front matter for each file rather than in front matter defaults.

Comment: Looks like it unfortunately.